# Help with Tabularx

Tags: tables, pdftex, tabularx

Hello I have this table

```
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |X|X|X|X|X| }
    \hline
    $n$ & 50 & 100 & 200  & 500 \\
    \hline 
    $t_{rel}$  & 250  & 1013  & 4052 & 25330  \\
    \hline
    $\tilde t_{rel}$  & 29.43 & 58.3  & 124.4 & 250 \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
```

for different values of $n$ you get different values of $t_{rel}$ and $\tilde t_{rel}$. The problem is that in the pdf it doesn't look good at all, you can't even see the "tilde" sign for $\tilde t_{rel}$. I am not familiar with tabulax Can anyone help me?

Comment: I would not use `tabularx` for tables of data like this just use a normal tabular. The setting of the entries is unrelated to the table `\tilde{t}{\mathrm{rel}}` should make  a t with a tilde accent and subscript rel, do you not see that in your output? (note it should be `\mathrm{rel}` not `rel` unless you mean the product `r*e*l`)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`booktabs`](//ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) for your presentation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ S[table-format=3] S[table-format=5] S[table-format=3.1,table-auto-round] }
  \toprule
  {$n$} & {$t_{\mathrm{rel}}$} & {$\tilde{t}_{\mathrm{rel}}$} \\
  \midrule
  50 & 250 & 29.43 \\
  100 & 1013 & 58.3 \\
  200 & 4052 & 124.4 \\
  500 & 25330 & 250.0 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The horizontal alignment of numbers make for an easier gauge on their respective magnitudes.

Answer (score 1):

I would typeset this table as follows:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l S[table-format=3.2] *2{S[table-format=4.1]} S[table-format=5]}
  \toprule
  $n$ & 50 & 100 & 200  & 500 \\
  $t_{rel}$  & 250  & 1013  & 4052 & 25330  \\
  $\tilde t_{rel}$  & 29.43 & 58.3  & 124.4 & 250 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]